# \leaders when at the start of the line

Tags: plain-tex, leaders

I'm encountering an issue where I have `\leaders` that occasionally fall at the beginning of the line and as a result, there are no leaders appearing.

I have for example:

```
\hsize 9.2cm

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\leaders\hbox{.}\hfill 2

\end
```

and this produces:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ............................ 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
2
```

If I add `\penalty0\hbox{}\penalty10000` before the `\leaders`, I get

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ............................ 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
....................................................... 2
```

But what I really want is this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ............................ 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit .................................................. 2
```

I've tried adding `\penalty` and other things but nothing I try seems to give me the desired result. Am I overlooking something simple?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Seamus: I'm not using LaTeX.

Comment: @dreamlax Compilable example is sufficient.

Comment: @dreamlax Sorry, that's just a stock block of text we use. Most people who need to be asked for a MWE will be using LaTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Glue (and leaders) are removed at a line break; so your idea of adding `\nobreak` is good, but you spoil it with `\penalty0` that introduces a feasible line break before the empty box and the leaders.

Just use `\nobreak`. I also add some fixed width so some dots are printed anyway and `\raggedright`.

```
\def\mydotfill{\unskip\nobreak\leaders\hbox{.}\hskip 4em plus 1fill\relax}

\hsize 8.5cm \raggedright

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\mydotfill 1

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\mydotfill 2

\end
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. It's currently 5:32 Saturday morning and I have been up all Friday night (that explains the `\penalty0`).

Comment: Perhaps relevant explanation of the first statement by the same poster https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443672/183051