# Problem with \hrulefill

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

(Note: `\parindent` is set to 0, for the sake better appearance.)

```
\noindent\hrulefill\par %With one single \hrulefill I get nothing.
a\hrulefill b\par %As desired.
\noindent\hrulefill b\par %As desired.
a\hrulefill\par %The "a" is there, but \hrulefill is not.
\hbox to\hsize{\hrulefill} %As desired
```

[image: Result]

The behaviour of `\hrulefill` in the 5 examples above really puzzles me. I thought that TeX should pack the entire line (with `\parfillskip` of course) into an hbox of width `\hsize` in all cases, but the result above tells me that I must be wrong. Just what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using plain TeX. Let's see the definition of `\hrulefill` on line 707 of `plain.tex`:

```
\def\hrulefill{\leaders\hrule\hfill}
```

What happens if you do

```
a\hrulefill\par
```

like in your third example? Well, the standard behavior of `\par` applies, which is explained on page 286 of the TeXbook.

> ▪ `\par`. 
>   The primitive `\par` command, also called `\endgraf` in plain TeX,
>   does nothing in restricted horizontal mode. But it terminates horizontal
>   mode: The current list is finished off by doing `\unskip\penalty10000\hskip\parfillskip`, then it is broken into lines as explained in Chapter 14,
>   and TeX returns to the enclosing vertical or internal vertical mode.
>   The lines of the paragraph are appended to the enclosing vertical list,
>   interspersed with interline glue and interline penalties, and with
>   the migration of vertical material that was in the horizontal list.
>   Then TeX exercises the page builder.

Since `\hrulefill` *is* glue, it is removed by `\unskip`.

If you look in the source for the TeXbook, you'll discover that `\hrulefill` is only used in boxes, either explicitly built with `\line` or in tabular material.

Compare with LaTeX’s definition:

```
% latex.ltx, line 616:
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hfill\kern\z@}
```

The `\leavevmode` starts horizontal mode if necessary; the leaders are not removed by `\par` because `\unskip` doesn't remove kerns.

In plain TeX, if you use `\hrulefill` in vertical mode you get an error

```
! Leaders not followed by proper glue.
<to be read again> 
                   \hfill
```

because it doesn't start horizontal mode. And if followed by `\par` it vanishes.

Now, why does TeX remove glue when it finishes off a paragraph? The usual method for ending a paragraph is not appending `\par`, but leaving a blank line:

```
This is a paragraph.

This is another one.
```

The blank line is by rule converted to a `\par` token, so we get the equivalent of

```
This is a paragraph. \par
This is another one.
```

and the trailing space coming from conversion of the end-of-line has to be removed or it could influence the line breaking. In some cases it could lead to an unwanted blank line containing only `\parfillskip` glue, when the last line is almost full.

Comment: So what is the point of removing the last glue when finishing a paragraph?

Comment: @user5938 `this ends a paragraph.<blank line>` will have a trailing space and `\unskip` removes it.